# lm function in R is excluding 1 dummy variable

Tags: r, regression, lm, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      Date    A      B      MONTH
2016-01-01    3     10    January
2016-01-02    5     13    January
2016-01-03    8     12    January
.
.
.
2016-12-29    4     13   December
2016-12-30    5     12   December
2016-12-31    6      4   December
```

With this dataframe, I want to run a regression model with the Month column as dummy variables.

I have tried two methods to run this and each time I do it, it always excludes the month "April".

Any idea why this may be happening?

1st method:

lm(A ~ MONTH + B, data = df)

Example output:

```
Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        7.248e+01  3.600e+01   0.902  0.36754    
MONTHAugust        7.425e+02  3.630e+01   6.680 9.29e-11 ***
MONTHDecember     -1.840e+02  3.277e+01  -5.613 4.02e-08 ***
MONTHFebruary     -8.673e+00  2.855e+01  -0.129  0.89770    
MONTHJanuary      -4.084e+01  2.945e+01  -0.368  0.71291    
MONTHJuly          9.407e+02  3.100e+01   4.540 7.73e-06 ***
MONTHJune          3.387e+01  3.077e+01   2.401  0.01687 *  
MONTHMarch         2.797e+02  2.884e+01   6.231 1.32e-09 ***
MONTHMay          -9.500e+01  3.122e+01  -3.043  0.00252 ** 
MONTHNovember     -1.321e+01  3.555e+01  -1.778  0.07626 .  
MONTHOctober       7.145e+01  3.200e+01   0.983  0.32637    
MONTHSeptember     9.691e+02  3.916e+01   4.319 2.04e-05 ***
B                  5.279e-02  1.161e-03  11.013  < 2e-16 ***
```

2nd Method:

A <- model.matrix(A ~ B + MONTH, df)

head(A)

```
  (Intercept) Sum.of.Media.Cost MONTHAugust MONTHDecember MONTHFebruary MONTHJanuary MONTHJuly MONTHJune MONTHMarch MONTHMay
1           1                 0           0             0             0            
1         0         0          0        0
2           1                 0           0             0             0            
1         0         0          0        0
3           1                 0           0             0             0            
1         0         0          0        0
4           1                 0           0             0             0            
1         0         0          0        0
5           1                 0           0             0             0            
1         0         0          0        0
6           1                 0           0             0             0            
1         0         0          0        0
  MONTHNovember MONTHOctober MONTHSeptember
1             0            0              0
2             0            0              0
3             0            0              0
4             0            0              0
5             0            0              0
6             0            0              0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `A ~ B + MONTH -1` -- if your dummies are complete, their linear combination is the same as the constant.  Hence reduced rank, and you cannot do that so something has to give.

*Either* you keep the constant (and remove one monthly dummy) to produce "per month offset to intercept", or, and that is what I would do, remove the constant to get "monthly intercept".

Comment: When I tried that, all of my dummy variable coefficients changed and my B column stayed the same. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, in your previous version, the coeficcients for each dummy was the difference from the effect of a specific month and the reference (April), which was included in the intercept.  In this second version, the coefficients represent effects of months themselves, not the difference from a reference.

Your new coefficient is probably the previous intercept + coefficient.

Comment: Yup that's exactly what happened. Thank you that makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: Also, just to add to this....should the R^2 change? My R^2 changed from .76 to .96 when I did this

Answer (score 3):

When you deal with dummy variables it's normal. If you have n levels for your factor variable, then you need only n-1 dummy variables. Since the remaining case is when all the dummy variables are zero. I think that April is the month excluded beacause is the first one if you consider alphabetical ordering.